# Simple vs Continuous in the Past Tense and in the Future Tense

Tags: tenses

Even though I understand the difference between the simple and the continuous aspect of the English tense system, I sometimes struggle to understand what each of these two aspects expresses in some past and future contexts. Let me give you two examples:

> 1a. *When I was a teenager I sometimes **called** my father.*
>
> 1b. *When I was a teenager I sometimes **was calling** my father.*
>
> 2a. *This is the last time we are seeing each other. I will sometimes **call** you.*
>
> 2b. *This is the last time we are seeing each other. I will be sometimes **calling** you.*

I get the meaning expressed by the past simple and the future simple in the above example sentences but I`m not feeling the continuous. Could you tell me what meaning does the continuous aspect convey in those?

Comment: I hope someone expert in grammar answers this question. Are sentences 2 and 4 correct grammatically?

Answer (score 0):

I hope the following will be useful, though I am not sure I can express it in the correct grammatical terms

> When I was a teenager I sometimes called my father
>   -- the phrase above is ok
>
> When I was a teenager I sometimes was calling my father
>   -- the phrase above sounds wrong

Can I suggest the following two modified sentences, which both sound correct to illustrate the difference.

> When I was a teenager I always called my father on Sunday evenings
>
> When I was a teenager I was always calling my father

same for the future

- This is the last time we are seeing each other. I will sometimes call you
   
  vs
- This is the last time we are seeing each other. I will be sometimes calling you

The first phrase sounds ok, but the second one sounds wrong because sometimes means only from time to time, not continuously.

Comment: Thanks tom. What would you say the difference is between the two following sentences?:

When I was a teenager I always called my father /vs/

When I was a teenager I was always calling my father

Comment: @user122524 the second version means that you were always calling him (night and day perhaps) the first version does not sound correct, it needs to be at specific times e.g. always called my father when I couldn't do my maths homework.

Comment: When I was a teenager, I was always calling my father during the week.

Comment: No, as a rule, don't suggest corrections. answer the question, dont question the question and don't question your answer.